# How to add custom html class to "Sign Out" button in magento 2

Tags: frontend, magento2.3.1, class, logout

How to add custom HTML class to "Sign Out" button in magento2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add class using jQuery also. Create one custom JS file and include it in  section.
Add below code in your JS file:

```
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".authorization-link a").addClass("sl-custom-class");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you works

Answer (score 1):

May be help you .
**/Magento_theme/templates/html/header.phtml**

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) : ?>
    <span class="header_account_link_list logout">
        <a class= "header_account_link" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl("customer/account/logout");?>"><?php echo __('Logout')?></a>
    </span>
<?php else: ?>
    <span class="header_account_link_list login">
        <a class= "header_account_link" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl("customer/account/login");?>"><?php echo __('Sign in')?></a>
    </span>
<?php endif;?>
```

And more information link :-

**https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Magento2-3-add-custom-login-and-logout-button/td-p/121047**